# Open and manipulate some Data in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have several files, such as a txt file. I'd like that Qt opens the files and at the end, or in a particular line which inserts something like

**done by @Me.**

Does somebody has any idea ?

Comment: I have lots of ideas!

Comment: Can you give me an idea ?

Comment: Please try _at least_ reading the docs (specifically the tutorials and examples) before posting.

Comment: I was just kidding, @SDE. You haven't shown any code that proves you've actually tried to solve your own problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
QFile textFile("/path/to/file");
if (textFile.open(QFile::ReadWrite | QFile::Append | QFile::Text) {
    textFile.write("done by @Me");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work sir.

```
QFile file(filepath);  

if (file.open(QFile::QIODevice::ReadWrite)) {
    QString data = file.readAll();
    data.append("done by @Me");
    file.write(data);
    file.close();
}
```

I'd suggest using it if the file is relatively small.